# How can I fix caret issues in a contenteditable that contains non-editable HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

What I am having is a `contenteditable` `div` that is supposed to contain addtional *unmodifiable* HTML content. Something like this:

```
<div id="txt" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="tagged" id="annyoing-html" contenteditable="false" style="display: initial;">
    <span>I annoy people!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the cursor/caret does not play well with this e.g. you won't see the caret blinking unless you type something. The same problem comes with the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keys - sometimes the caret just disappears and the only thing that makes it re-appear is typing something.

I thought I could just insert text nodes that would make the caret jump correctly:

```
insertWhitespace = function() {

  var contentEditable = document.getElementById("txt");
  var element = document.getElementById("annyoing-html");

  var textNodeLeft = document.createTextNode("");
  var textNodeRight = document.createTextNode("");

  contentEditable.insertBefore(textNodeLeft, element);

  if(element.nextSibling != null) {     
    contentEditable.insertBefore(textNodeRight, element.nextSibling);  
  } else {
    element.appendChild(textNodeRight);
  }
};
```

but that does not work the way I thought it would..

First of all the caret does not "blink" the way it should and additionally the zero-width whitespace character `\u200b` does still count as a character which means you have to press <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> one time additionally to jump over that invisible character ..

Just try the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdtv1djk/1/) and try to add text to the left and right side of the non-editable content. Clicking the button will just add those zw whitespaces but your cursor won't blink.

Of course I tried to remove the content after inserting it but I think Chrome simply removes the text node.

So what can I do to arrive at a "*natural*" feel for my `contenteditable`?

Comment: which browser are you using? I'm using firefox-45.0.2

Comment: @SalathielGenèse Chrome/Firefox but I'd like to make it work on all browsers :)